# Drag&Drop Images from a folder to a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, wysiwyg

I want to implement a `JTextPane` to edit text, using images I drag and drop from my system into the `JTextPane`. I tried to implement it by using `JTextPane` as superclass and `DropTargetListener` as Interface. But when i'm trying to read my InputStream I get a `NullPointerException`. Please help.

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class JTextTest extends JTextPane implements DropTargetListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JTextTest() {
    new DropTarget(this, this);
    this.setDragEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent arg0) {
}

@Override
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dropTargetDropEvent) {
    System.out.println("Drop event");
    Transferable transferable = dropTargetDropEvent.getTransferable();
    for (DataFlavor d : transferable.getTransferDataFlavors()) {
        if (d.isRepresentationClassInputStream()) {
            dropTargetDropEvent
                    .acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
            try {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
                        (InputStream) transferable.getTransferData(d));

                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(is));
                this.insertIcon(image);
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        } else {
            dropTargetDropEvent.rejectDrop();
        }
    }
    dropTargetDropEvent.getDropTargetContext().dropComplete(true);
}

@Override
public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent arg0) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this snippet,

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(createImageInputStream(is)));
```

The ImageIO.read() expects a [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) ,[ImageInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream.html) ,[InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) or [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and note that while dealing with images,most of the `NullPointerException` is thrown when there is a problem (more specifically reading the image returns null)  with the image, image source or reading from that source.

Comment: You mean ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is) ?